# bufferedReader reader.readline directly goes back to null

Tags: java, json, android-studio, bufferedreader

I'm using a bufferedReader and strangely, after i do this

```
reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
```

**EDIT3:** the BufferedReader reader itself is know fully loaded and correct, but the reader.readline, which is needed, goes directly back to null

Could anyone explain me what i do wrong or why this happens?

**EDIT :** i get json from the url which is this

> {"sports":[{"sport":{"id":"1","name":"yoga","rating":"1.6"}},{"sport":{"id":"2","name":"tennis","rating":"3.6"}},{"sport":{"id":"3","name":"zwemmen","rating":"4.7"}}],"view":{"name":"SportData","display":"page_1","path":"admin/content/data/view/SportData","root":"sports","child":"sport","pages":null,"page":null,"count":3,"limit":null}}

So when i debug this, i get following....

[image: running bufferedReader]
[image: running reader.readline]

**EDIT2:** this is the full code for this,

```
@Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... type) {
        URL_STRING = "my json_url";
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
            try
            {
                URL url;
                StringBuilder stringBuilder;
                    url = new URL(URL_STRING);
                    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                    connection.connect();
                    reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
                    stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                    while ((line =reader.readLine()) != null)
                    {
                        stringBuilder.append(line+"\n");
                    }
                    result =  stringBuilder.toString();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure that the first line is not empty in your inputstream?

Comment: see the watches, the inputstream is not empty, if i debug further, the connection.getInputStream keeps all the data but the bufferedReader doesn't

Comment: null means  if the end of the stream has been reached check Is connection.getInputStream() is valid and is it returning correct, because looks like it

Comment: everything in the connection.getInpuStream is correct, i see the json in there and it stays there, so that's good. I also added a watch on reader itself and in there, it also stands good, so it has to do with reader and reader.readline....

Comment: Illegible. Don't post pictures of text here. Post the text.

Comment: Please prefer pasting the code directly in your question in the correct format over attaching snaps of your IDE window.

Comment: Can you paste the code? We don't have to "guess" your code to help you.

Comment: 'The reader is back to null' is meaningless, and there is nothing here that indicates that the input stream is not empty. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: @Çağatay Barın, added the needed code.

Comment: The code you have just posted (a) is wrong and (b) agrees with neither my answer nor what is displayed in your IDE snapshots. It remains unclear what you're asking.

Comment: this code is not wrong, it's part of my splashscreen code and it fully worked with XML

Comment: It most certainly is wrong. It throws away every odd numbered line. Either this isn't the real code or it doesn't work. Period. Have another look at what you posted, and while you're at it explain the difference between it and what's displayed in the IDE snapshots. And then explain what your question means.

Comment: it is the real code and it works till the while loop

Comment: In other words it doesn't work, which is exactly what I just said, and it remains different from the IDE snapshots, so it can't be the real code, as I also just said. When are you goi to explain that?  When are you going to try it with the code in my answer? Why are you arguing with people who are trying to help you?

Comment: @EJP the only difference between snapshot and code is that in the snapshot i first put the reader.readline to line and in the code, i do it inside the while loop

Comment: but everything i try, it doesn't work, neither your answer

Comment: That's what I said. it's different. Both are wrong. It is pointless to discuss it further. Try it my way some time. You might get a surprise. I don't know what the point of posting questions here is if you're not going to take any notice of the answers.

Comment: Define "doesn't work". You've been asked that before.

Comment: @EJP look at my code, and for you, i'll get another snapshot to let you see that your answer also wont work. doesn't work = from the moment the line *reader= new BufferedReader....* is processed, the variable String reader is back to null

Comment: I've not only looked at your code, I've told you what's wrong with it, and how to fix it too. I don't want a snapshot. I want an explanation of what "doesn't work" means. I don't see any evidence anywhere that anything isn't working. The code I posted has been working for me for 21 years, and for a lot of other people as well.

Comment: How can i give evidence if you can only see "it" in the IDE window??

Comment: I don't know what '`String` reader variable' you're talking about. If you mean the `BufferedReader`, it isn't null, and there is no evidence here to the contrary. If you mean `String line;`, it isn't 'back to null' at that point. It is *still null* from its declaration. You haven't assigned it to anything yet at the point where you create the `BufferedReader`. This is making absolutely zero sense. 'Evidence' would constitute a concrete problem, such as unexpected data, output, or an exception. All we have here so far is a series of impossible claims.

Comment: oops my mistake, i  mean the BufferedReader reader is going directly back to null. But the problem is that the reader is null, while it should have the json in it

Comment: The read cannot be null, this is only a failure in the debuger.

Comment: @tak3shi, why does it works great for an xml url, but not for the json url? it's just the same code and with xml, the reader.readline isn't null

Comment: read.readline ? You have talked about the reader!

Comment: If the line is null it means that you have reached the end. See solution from EJP. He has corrected your code.

Comment: i do know that, but it's at the beginning, and as you can see, the reader itself isn't null anymore, but at the beginning of the while(not yet executed it), it's already null...             that's why i implemented the snapshots, there you can easily see that after the line {reader = new BufferedReader(....)} is executed, everythings fine, but if you go to the next line {stringBuilder = new ...}, you can see that the reader.readline is again null, which in my opinion just can't

Comment: sorry, i have no idea what you are talking about.

Comment: after i execute this { reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));}, the reader and reader.readline has the correct values, but if i go one step forward, in my case to the { stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();}, the reader.readline is null

Comment: because you are reading the next line with each readLine() call. Thats what EJP has corrected.

Comment: and the reader itself, was the main problem, but that i fixed, that was just one number too much in the url

Comment: i implemented EJP's answer but it doesn't work either, it's still the same and if you look at the code i editted above, it stands there like EJP suggested

Comment: No you didn't. After 75 attempts your IDE snapshots still don't agree with the code posted. And you still haven't described an actual problem, only a perfectly understandable IDE symptom. *Of course* `readLine()` shows as null after the loop. **That's why it terminated.** I've had enough of this nonsense.

Comment: off course it's null after the loop, but it's null before the loop even began

Comment: Again, no idea, what your problem is. When you check your screenshots, you will see a json response.

Comment: I think, you are focusing too much on the debugger output. But debuggers are implemented differently in each IDE and do not always show the truth. For example using a watch over read.realine() is a very bad idea. Some debuggers are executing the method, other return a cached value.

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't make sense. You're appending the same line forever. Your loop should be:

```
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
{
    stringBuilder.append(line+"\n");
}
```

I'm also wondering whether you're creating two `BufferedReaders` on the same socket, which doesn't make sense either.

Comment: i only created one BufferedReader. at the top of my activity i just say {BufferedReader reader;} and in the method i create it

Comment: and i also tried this, but not working either, perhaps it has something to do with json, that it's not compatible with my structure, because if i try the same thing but with an XML file, it works

Comment: It has nothing to with the data and everything to do with your incorrect code.

Comment: and btw, i've put an xml file in it and then my code works